# objc_msgSend KVO crashing

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im seeing a crash in foundation library. Im a bit confused on if this crash is due to the object thats observing has been deallocated or if they object thats being observed got deallocated.

Can anyone give any insight on this?

```
    0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000183902f70 objc_msgSend + 16
    1   Foundation                           0x0000000185902210 -[NSKeyValueObservance observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 420
    2   Foundation                           0x00000001858de234 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 300
    3   Foundation                           0x00000001858ddd54 NSKeyValueDidChange + 400
    4   Foundation                           0x0000000185995224 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKeys:count:maybeOldValuesDict:usingBlock:] + 776
    5   Foundation                           0x00000001858dd220 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObservingPrivate) _changeValueForKey:key:key:usingBlock:] + 60
    6   Foundation                           0x0000000185901204 _NSSetObjectValueAndNotify + 264
```

Comment: Sadly without context we'd be completely guessing. Do you know roughly where the crash occurs? Can you show us some code?

Comment: The crash report should show the name of the method that was being invoked. What was it? If you can reproduce it when running under the debugger, then you can use the information [here](http://sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html) can help you figure out which message was being sent. Also, if you can reproduce the issue when running under the Zombies instrument that will likely be very informative.

Comment: If you are unable to figure out the cause yourself, then if you can provide the full project, then I (or somebody else, I'm sure) would be happy to take a look and let you know what is going on.